# Misunderstanding with password verifying php

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to verify user's login and compare two passwords (they are hashed in the database). Im pretty sure its just some stupid mistake or error that I can't find. This is how I hash when saving into db. `$password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`
And this is my login method:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM users WHERE username=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

            $username = $_POST["username"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($result);

            if(password_verify($password, $result)){
                header("Location: http://localhost/test2/Home.php");
            }
            else{
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Something went wrong!')</script>";
                echo $mysqli->error;
                echo $stmt->error;
            }
        }
```

For testing purposes Im trying to `echo` errors, but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Executed query returns any results ?

Comment: you are inserting password in hash encryption and while login comparing by original password

Comment: @NavinBhandari ```$password``` is the ```$_POST```, Assuming ```$result``` is the encrypted password.

Comment: i think problem in your bind_param **$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM users WHERE username=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);**  this should be **$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM users WHERE :username");
            $stmt->bind_param("username", $username);**

Comment: you have used $username in $stmt->bind_param("s", $username); but you are defining variable after that So the select query will not give any result. You need to put variables before prepare mysql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget to fetch data form  query result

```
$stmt->execute();// execute query
$stmt->bind_result($result);// bind result
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {// fetch data
        $pass = $result;
    }
    if (password_verify($password, $pass)) {
        header("Location: http://localhost/test2/Home.php");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped! Im new to `php` so I was not aware of the `fetch()` method. From reading manual I understood that it returns either `true` or `false` which is handy for checking with `if` or `while`. Do I need to fetch data on every database method when Im retrieving something?

Comment: No its not return true of false its Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Thank you again. One more question, now I get this error on the page:  `Undefined variable: pass in /var/www/html/test2/Login.php on line 37` The line is `if (password_verify($password, $pass))` Any idea why it says this? I added the code you supplied me and basically `$pass` variable is defined couple lines before where we assign it to `$result`

Comment: Are you able to fetch data form you query?? Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php to check number of result return by your query!!

Comment: Im not sure if this is what you are asking, but I tried `echo` `$stmt->fetch()` and I got result of `1`

Comment: @Viktor in your code, just add this line `$stmt->fetch();` after `$stmt->bind_result($result);` Do only that and nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
if(password_verify($password, $result)){
```

To

```
if(password_verify($password, $result['password'])){
```

Comment: I am afraid you don't quite understand what a $result is.